# How to pass data from tableviewcontroller to view controller when using parse for IOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have the following class. It saves data to parse,com database and it works properly. there are 8 fields.

Period1,
period2,
period3,
period4,
period5,
period6,
period7 and 
period8

My app has user and each user is linked to a schedule.
In my tableview, I did

```
cell.textlabel.text = @"name";
```

When I try to pass the data through the prepare for segue method
everyones schedule(which are supposed to be different for everyone) is the same as the first one in the database.

Here is the code

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        self.parseClassName = @"Student";


    }

    return self;
}


-(PFQuery *)queryForTable
{




    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Student"];

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        [query whereKey:@"identifier" equalTo:@"okay"];
    }


    return query;


}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}




//added now
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{






    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detail"])
    {

        ATDetailViewController *at = [segue destinationViewController];
        at.per1 = @"This is a test";

    }


}
@end




// detail view controller.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.period1.text = self.per1;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Student"];
    [query whereKey:@"first_name" equalTo:@"bob"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];


}
```

---

For some reason, all of the detail views for all of the rows show the same data.
How do I differentiate the user?

I'm pretty sure my problem is in the prepare for segue method but I don't know what it is.

Comment: You say you're trying to pass data in `prepareForSegue` but all I see you passing is one string.  (`at.per1 = @"This is a test";`)

Comment: I know i just want it to work for this one string so i can learn how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand.  How do you expect different results if you always do the same thing?

Comment: I realized that u have to pass the pfObject thrugh the segue and then it worked Thanks